# Alguien me podría ayudar diciéndome como colocar un temporizador en este código?

Tags: java

```
package proyecto;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class culebrita extends PApplet {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            PApplet.main("proyecto.culebrita");
          }

      int filas = 20;
      int columnas = 20;

      int bs = 20;

      ArrayList<Integer> posX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> posY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      int dir=2;

      int[] dx = {0, 0, -1, 1};
      int[] dy = {-1, 1, 0, 0};

      int appleX;
      int appleY;

      boolean gameOver=true;
      boolean modeEpilepsia=false;

     int cont=0;

      public void settings() {
            size(400, 400 );
        }

    public void setup() {

            frameRate(10);

            //posision inicial - mitad de la pantalla
            posX.add(10);
            posY.add(10);

            appleX = (int) random(0, 20);
            appleY = (int) random(0, 20);
        }

      public void draw() {

          if (modeEpilepsia) {

              background((int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255));

          } else {

                  background(255);
              }

          if (gameOver) {

              textSize(20);

              //texto y posicion en la pantalla

                text("Presione SPACE para iniciar.", 80, height/2);
              } 

          else {

              //se generan las lineas de la cuadricula

              for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                  line(0, i*bs, width, i*bs);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                  line(j*bs, 0, j*bs, height);
                }


                //movimiento de la serpiente
                //agrega al arraylist la posicion segun su direccion
                posX.add(0, posX.get(0)+dx[dir]);
                posY.add(0, posY.get(0)+dy[dir]);
                posX.remove(posX.size()-1);
                posY.remove(posY.size()-1);

                //al chocar algun borde de la pantalla se termina el juego
                if ( ( posX.get(0)<0 )||( posX.get(0)>filas-1 )||( posY.get(0)<0 )||( posY.get(0)>columnas-1 ) ) {
                  gameOver=true;
                }

                //creciminto de la serpiente 
                //si la posicion de la serpiente es igual a la posicion de la manzana
                if ((posX.get(0)==appleX)&&(posY.get(0)==appleY)) {
                    //con cada manzana gana dos puntos
                    cont=cont+2;

                //la serpiente aumenta una posicion (la posicion donde estaba la manzana)
                  posX.add(appleX);
                  posY.add(appleY);

                //se genera una nueva manzana 
                  appleX = (int) random(0, 20);
                  appleY = (int) random(0, 20);
                  }

                //dibujar la manzana
                if (modeEpilepsia) {
                    //color random
                  fill((int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255));
                } else {
                    //color rojo
                  fill(255, 0, 0);
                }
                //posicion de la manzana y tamaño del cuadro bs=20
                rect(appleX*bs, appleY*bs, bs, bs);

                //si llega a x puntos se activa modeEpilepsia
                if (cont==4){
                    modeEpilepsia=!modeEpilepsia;
                }

                //dibujar la serpiente
                if (modeEpilepsia) {
                //color random de la serpiente
                  fill((int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255), (int) random(0, 255));
                } else {
                //color azul
                  fill(0, 0, 255);
                }
                //dibuja el tamaño de la serpiente segun las posiciones guardadas en el arraylist
                for (int i = 0; i < posX.size(); i++) {
                  rect(posX.get(i)*bs, posY.get(i)*bs, bs, bs);
                }
              }
            }

      //funcion que nos ayuda para conectar la letra presionada con el movimiento
            public void TeclaPresionada() {

              //activa modo epilepsia
              if (key=='m')modeEpilepsia=!modeEpilepsia;

              //mueve hacia arriba
              if (key=='w')dir=0;

              //mueve hacia abajo
              if (key=='s')dir=1;

              //mueve hacia la izquierda
              if (key=='a')dir=2;

              //mueve hacia la derecha
              if (key=='d')dir=3;

              //reinicia el juego
              if (key==' ') {
              //imprime los puntos
                  text("PUNTOS: "+ cont, 80, 80);
                gameOver=false;
              //contador se reanuda
                cont=0;
              //limpia las posiciones 
                posX.clear();
                posY.clear();
              //vuelven a posicion inicial
                posX.add(10);
                posY.add(10);
              //genera nuevamente las manzanas
                appleX = (int) random(0, 20);
                appleY = (int) random(0, 20);
              }
       } 
}
```

Comment: que es o que hace un temporizador?

Comment: En el codigo hay un contador, quiero que cuando el contador llegue a x valor se active el temporizador o cronometro. Que quiero hcer?

Comment: puedes usar un java.util.Timer como cronómetro. ¿que quieres que haga ese cronómetro en particular?

Comment: Hice una funcion se llama modeEpilepsia para cambiar de colores la culebrita, la manzana y el fondo **ramdomicamente**.Lo que quiero es que esa funcion se active cuando el contdor llegue a x valor(puntos) pero que sea en un tiempo limite (10 segundos). Como un bonus por llegar a cierto puntaje

Answer (score -1):

Primero haría una clase que es la que va a estar escuchando al cronómetro:

```
private class Cronometro extends java.util.TimerTask {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       System.out.println("Tiempo límite agotado");
       /*
         validar System.currentTimeMillis() contra el que haya tenido al llegar al bonus, si llegó
       */
   }
}
```

Luego agregaría un Temporizador a la clase donde lo requeriría.

```
private java.util.Timer temporizador;
```

Luego agregaría un método para validar si el contador ya requiere activar cronómetro:

```
void contadorHaCambiado(int contador) {
      if (contador == X ) {
          modoEpilepsia = true;
          long horaQueInicioTiempoBonus = System.currentTimeMillis();
          if (temporizador == null) {
              temporizador = new java.util.Timer();
          }
          long retrazo = 10 * 1000; //10 segundos
          timer.schedule(new Cronometro(), retrazo);
}
```

Faltaría que agregues una bandera para saber si logró bonus y a que hora, para poder validar cuando te avise el Cronómetro.

Pero es recomendable que leas bien las especificaciones de java.util.Timer ya que tiene varios métodos conforme a diferentes necesidades. Y como se ejecuta en otro hilo (thread) es importante entenderlo bien.

Te paso ligas:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Oye amigo muchas gracias por responder, voy a hacer lo que dices y te cuento a ver como me fue :) @AlbertoLopez